# Creating a $C^2$ smooth convex curve which joins circular arcs

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, plane-curves

Suppose that I have many points $p_1$,..., $p_n$, all very close to origin 0. For R very, very large, I have circular arcs of radius R, $\alpha_i$, about $p_i$. I do not speak about their parameterization because in my question I will allow the re-parameterization of arcs.

Suppose that:

1) Gauss map is injective on $\cup im(\alpha_i)$ meaning even for different arc, no two normal vector can be the same.

2) Suppose the Gauss map cover most of the circle except for some small intervals of angles $[\theta_i,\theta_{i+1}]$

It can sometimes be obstructed to interpolate these curves together to be a C^2 convex simple, closed, curve. This is because it is easy to construct examples where there are lines which intersect multiple arcs along the same *ray*.

Question: If I fix a $\theta_i, \theta_{i+1}$ window, for what R can I interpolate these arcs (i.e. introduce smooth small curves connecting them) together to get the $C^2$ smooth convex, simple, closed, curve (allowing re-parameterization of the circular arcs)? Is there an explicit way to perform this interpolation?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. But usually, if you join degree-1 curves (segments) you have only continuity, if you join degree-2 curves you have only $C^1$, and so on...

Comment: Oh sorry my english not very good. Arcs do not intersect. I want do not want to joint these curves, I want to interpolate between these circular arcs!